# How to write interface for reusable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing table component with React and Typscript. I want to make my component fully reusable, that it can get any date from server and put it in props. Thus it can have many different columns and header.

My problem is how to write interface for that properly?

In the beginning I have such simple interface for data that my component can get.

```
interface IData {
  id: number;
}
```

But this data can be always different. It can be todos with different fields:

title: string, body: string

Or it can be users:

surname: string, name: string, email: string and so on

It means in props my component can get any data.

Moreover I want to let my component get different React.Nodes. For example, I want to put in my props checkboxes, buttons for deleting raws and so on.

How can I make my component reusable this way, that it can get any props that I give.

```
// here I want to put some reactNodes, it can be anything
interface IActions {

}
```

```
interface ITable extends IActions{
  headers: string[];
  body: I[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics.
For example:

```
export interface Iheader<T> {// T is a given generic (any custom type you use as datatype)
        id: string,
        name: string,
    //... any props you need
    }

export interface ITable<T> {
    
    items?:T[]//your data array
    //any props
    columns: Iheader<T>[],
    
}
```

Your core component should recieve generic type

```
export default function Table<T>(props:ITable<T>) {
    }
```

When this component need to be inserted somewhere, just specify your custom type as generic

```
<Table<YourType> //YourType is T
    columns={columns} //should be Iheader 
    items={data} //should be YourType
/>
```